# ZF1 Get errors before redirect

Tags: php, zend-framework, redirect

As the title says, I want to get all errors before the redirect. So this is my case:

I have a select for changing databases(identical structure but different data);
So let's say I am here: `localhost/user/edit/id/100 (database 1)`
on db change, I am redirecting the user to the same page, but we load data from database 2.
If it is not found, I get an error:

`"Fatal error: Call to a member function on a non-object ..."`

How do I catch the errors before the redirect occurs in order to change the url?
Thanks!

Comment: But this error appears _after_ you redirect someone so you cannot catch it before redirecting (or i misunderstood your explanation). Also you cannot catch fatal errors with try/catch block. You need to register shutdown function http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php

Answer (score 0):

Use [try {} catch() {}](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.exceptions.php) for catching errors before redirect.

```
try {
    if (/* if error occured */) {
        throw new \Exception('Error occured');
    }
} catch(\Exception $e) {
    // redirect with error occured
}

// redirect without error
```

*In Zend maybe need to use `return $redirectObj`, I don't know Zend well.*

In your case, try to do this:

```
try { 
    if ( ! $this->getResponse()) {
        throw new Exception('Error occured! Can not get response object');
    }

    return $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
} catch (Exception $e) { 
    echo $e->getMessage(); 
    die(); 
}
```

Comment: Already tried this:
try
    {
      $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
      echo "<pre>"; print_r($e); echo "</pre>"; die();
    }

and it is not working; It appears that this type of error it is not cached by zend;

Comment: Still not working. The redirect occurs and I receive same error
"Fatal error: Call to a member function on a non-object ... "

Comment: Is method `$this->getResponse()` really work in Zend1? Maybe you forgot to extends base controller in your own controller?

Comment: For example, try to extend `Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract` class

Comment: Or try to use `header("Location: http://generated_url_with_zend");` PHP function at last.

Comment: The problem is not the redirection but the fact that zend does not catch E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR and returns it as a simple E_ERROR;